# Eclipse repeat the same message again and again on a twig file

Tags: eclipse, twig, dltk

I have installed **Eclipse luna**, and then **php editor**, **symfony plugin** and **twig editor**.

Now Eclipse displays a message when I am working on twig file:

> The resource is not on the script path of a Script project.

But it display not only one time, it would be ok if so, but again and again like spam or flooding.

After searching the string on github, I found that the culprit was the dynamic language toolkit, but I cannot unsinstall it (because it is required).

Comment: I was using Eclipse but switched to Netbeans when I started coding using Twig (within Symfony2). It works well, but I found PHPStorm strongly faster (even if it costs about $80...).

Comment: I test Netbeans, but i didn't like it, so i use Sublime text to edit twig files. Komodo edit was a good one, but code formatter were missing. PHPStorm is supposed to be free for opensource project, but i don't really understand what is VCS.

Comment: It happened to me today. Any answer ?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is fixed by me here : https://github.com/pdt-eg/Core-Plugin/pull/78

Will be released with next Core-Plugin version

Comment: Any idea when this will go live? I'm still getting this error using PDT Ext Core Plugin ver 0.19.0.201310280702. I assume it has not gone live yet?

Comment: I should get all permissions to this project in this week. After this I'll release new version ASAP.